# Using a named integer in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have used the below code to find a corresponding date from a specified cell which gives me a row number as an integer. The problem I have is that I want to use this in a range that uses the row number twice to determine the start cell and end cell of the range. I am getting the 'Run-time error'1004' - 'Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed.

How can I use this named integer twice to get what I need? I am getting the error on my last row of code.

```
Set MacroPage = Workbooks("Monthly Inventory Report 2.xlsm").Worksheets("Macro Page")
Set BHLSTracker = Workbooks("Monthly Inventory Report 2.xlsm").Worksheets("Blackhole & Lost Stock Tracker")

Dim DataDate As String: DataDate = MacroPage.Range("D4").Value
Dim TargetDate As Range, TargetRow As Integer
    Set TargetDate = BHLSTracker.Columns("A").Find(What:=CDate(DataDate), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    If Not TargetDate Is Nothing Then TargetRow = TargetDate.Row
    
BHLSTracker.Range("E1:F1").Copy
BHLSTracker.Range(Cells(TargetRow, 5), Cells(TargetRow, 6)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

Comment: you need to qualify `Cells(TargetRow...`, else VBA will use the cells of the Activesheet, and if  the `BHLSTracker`-Sheet is not the active sheet, this will fail. `BHLSTracker.Range(BHLSTracker.Cells(TargetRow, 5), BHLSTracker.Cells(TargetRow, 6)).PasteSpecial`

Comment: In addition to the above you are testing the `find` but you just move on regardless of whether `targetrow` gets assigned or not, that's gonna cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the swift responses. That works.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a VBA code to select a range that is not in the active worksheet, VBA will show you the run-time error 1004. Because, if you want to select a cell or range of cells for a particular worksheet needs to be active at that point. You cannot select a cell from sheet1 if sheet2 is active right now.

If you wish to access an inactive sheet, you must do so explicitly: `BHLSTracker.Cells(TargetRow,xColumn)`

Comment: Sure you can, you just have to qualify it.